# quotes not working in php

Tags: php, quotes

I am using php. This code does not work:

```
<?php
$str="<?palash";
print($str);
```

no output
but it works as soon as I introduce a space between < and ?

```
<?php
$str="< ?palash";
print($str);// prints '< ?palash'
```

Comment: Firstly, what is it exactly that you wish to do here? Plus, there is a "reason" as to why it's failing. I just need to remember where the docs are located for it.

Comment: i wish to create a php class using php itself dynamically so that it could store few enums that I fetch from the db. so it must have <?php in it. And when I try to write it to a file using a string, it stops the code in the above mentioned lines. @Fred-ii-

Comment: if you reload your first piece of code and view your HTML source, you will in fact see `<?palash`. It won't show up in your screen. so use `htmlentities()` as stated below, if that's what you wish to have.

Comment: Your code is most likely hitting a security limitation that prevents writing php with php at the server level (lower on the stack than PHP). There is really no logical reason to do it this way, and about a million security issues that can arise from doing it this way. Just put them in a JSON or .ini file and parse them that way, don't dynamically write php for this, that's a massive design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

you can also escape special characters by using a backslash `\` before the special character `?` that you want to escape

this will do what you're asking for

```
<?php
$str='<\?palash';
echo $str;
?>
```

cheers!

Comment: This, or `$str = "<"."?palash";`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't print `<b?palash` because it has *special characters* in it.

If you want to print string with special characters then you should use `htmlentities` function: `print htmlentities($str);`

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but your web browser interprets it as a broken HTML tag so it doesn't know what to do with your malformed HTML.

Try pressing Ctrl + U to view the source code.

Try this:

```
echo htmlentities("<?palash"); // produces &lt;?palash
```